# VIM Fuzzy Finder and l9 Errors upon startup

Tags: vim, plugins, gvim

I am getting the following errors in a pop up window titled Message when I start gVim 7.3.

```
Error detected while processing function <SNR>38_initialize: line 97:
E117: Unknown functino: fuf#addMode line 98:
E117: Unknown functino: fuf#addMode line 99:
E117: Unknown functino: fuf#addMode line 100:
...
E117: Unknown functino: fuf#addMode line 116:
E117: Unknown functino: fuf#addMode line 117:
Error detected while processing C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim73\plugin\l9.vim:
line 40:
E174: Command already exists: add ! to replace it
line 89:
E174: Command already exists: add ! to replace it
line 100:
E174: Command already exists: add ! to replace it
line 104:
E174: Command already exists: add ! to replace it
```

Then when I press **OK** gVim appears to start working fine. How would you suggest me to get rid of this popup and make **Fuzzy Finder** and **l9** work with out errors?

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue too, and it turned out that I had an older version of fuzzyfinder installed in standard .vim directories, and at the same time as a newer version installed using [pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen).  Deleting the older version fixed the issue.

Be sure to remove both the fuzzyfinder.vim file in plugins and the fuf.vim file in autoload.